# how to grant openLDAP user login in three Linux servers only

Tags: debian, openldap

I have `openldap` (`phpldapadmin`) that sync all users to Linux Debian servers,if I try to add LDAP user as Linux user I got error user already exist (I know its not a valid)

```
aabuhasna@qa:/$ who am i
aabuhasna pts/1        2016-06-16 03:38 (XXXXX)
aabuhasna@qa:/$ sudo adduser aabuhasna
[sudo] password for aabuhasna:
adduser: The user `aabuhasna' already exists.
aabuhasna@qa:/$ cat /etc/passwd |grep aabuhasna
aabuhasna@qa:/$
```

In the `openldap` if the user doesn't have `/bin/bash` as `loginshell` then he can NOT login to any server at all, my problem I want user only to access three servers only with his LDAP information,

My questions:

- Can I add the user to `/etc/passwd` as a workaround to make him login, if yes please advice about the correct way to add it.
- if option one is not valid (adding the user to `/etc/passwd`) is there a file that can be change to make exception for this use.

Comment: Take a look at the `pam_succeed_if` module and the `user ingroup group` operator.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish. The first is to use the `pam_access` module on each individual server to allow/disallow access on a per-user basis. The second is to use the `pam_check_host_attr` directive in `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`, enabling this on all servers, and then create an attribute:value pair associated with a given user ID for each server that user should be able to log in to.

For example, after enabling this on a hostname "gargoyle", if I want user `ben` to be able to login to that host, I must add the attribute/value pair "host:gargoyle" to `ben`'s LDAP entry.

Answer (score 0):

John's answer will work.

Alternatively, the `filter` statement in the `nss_ldap` or `nslcd` configurations allows you filter users by random LDAP filters; e.g.,

```
filter passwd (|(uidNumber=1234)(gidNumber=1234))
```

This example will only define users with uid or gid '1234' on the current machine. You can use any valid LDAP filter here. The difference with John's solution is that with this, the filtered-out users will not even exist on this server (I.e., `getent passwd` for these users will return nothing).